# How to handle Service Information in Android

Tags: android, message

Operator can send Service Information message to phone user. It appears as notification window. My operator for example sends spent and left money after every call. It uses these Service Information for that.

Is there a way to handle that message?

Answer (score 0):

If they are SMS (The case I see with operators around me).

Simple add an intent filter to your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example">
    <uses-permission id="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <application>
        <receiver class="SMSApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and just extends android.content.IntentReceiver and implement the onIntentReceived method as follows:

```
public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
                for (int i = 0; i &lt; messages.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage message = messages[i];
                    System.out.println("Received SMS from: "+message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());      
                    System.out.println(message.getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Than you. But they are not SMS. They are Service Notifications. I don't know how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the similar way parsing of USSD services is working. Have a look into the class that parses USSD reply: http://codepaste.ru/7545/. I hope this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: I tied this class. But IsFound() is always false. When I receive Service Information message it appears as OK dialog. So until I press OK button I can't use anything in phone. I'm not sure if it is ussd reply.

Comment: Try to run logcat and see what happens when this dialog appears: logcat -b main

Comment: And "logcat -v time -b main PhoneUtils:D" returns an empty string. On real device.

Comment: On "logcat -b main" the same. returns an empty string;

Comment: Try to connect your real device to a computer and run in the command line the following command adb logcat -v time -b main Then try to call somewhere and after that you'll receive message from the operator try to see in the log what has happened. If you manage to find what is happening then you'll have a possibility to create a parser. PhoneUtils:D parameter displays messages of minimum debug level for PhoneUtils TAG. But in your case this can be another TAG, or another log message level.

Comment: Then try to check simply adb logcat

Comment: Can't find anything. At least there is no message I receive in this log. Even adb logcat. I tried to find out where is it invoked and couldn't. May be I just don't have enough knowledge to understand this log.

Comment: Link not online anymore. If anyone has the code, it would be nice to have it!